# ModelState not show all errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a ASP NET Core 2.1 API with ActionFilter (auto ModelState validation is suppressed)  and when there is a bind error - for example not valid string to be bind to guid - Model State contains only the errors from binding but non of other errors - attribute required or MaxLength and so on. Is this something expected? And more important question: Is there a way to get all model state errors on one trip?

My Action filter (global):

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
    }
}
```

the Bind Model:

```
public class SkillBindDto
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.FieldRequired)]
    [MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.FieldInvalidMinLength)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Info { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.FieldRequired)]
    public Guid SectionId { get; set; }

    public string[] Tags { get; set; }
}
```

the Action method in the controller

```
[HttpPost()]
public async Task<ActionResult<IReadOnlyCollection<SkillDto>>> Create([FromBody]ICollection<SkillBindDto> skills, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    List<SkillDto> result = await _skillService.CreateSkillsAsync(skills, cancellationToken);

    return result;
}
```

And two examples:
When the body of the request is:

```
[
    {
        SectionId : "0c2d3928-aff2-44da-blaaah-blaaah", - this is invalid guid
        Name : "",
        Info : "Test Info",
        Tags : ["tag 1", "tag 2"]
    },
        {
        SectionId : "0c2d3928-aff2-44da-blaaah-blaaah", - this is invalid guid
        Name : "",
        Info : "Test Info 2",
        Tags : ["tag 3", "tag 2"]
    }
]
```

I get this response:

```
{
    "[0].SectionId": [
        "Error converting value \"0c2d3928-aff2-44da-blaaah-blaaah\" to type 'System.Guid'. Path '[0].SectionId', line 3, position 51."
    ],
    "[1].SectionId": [
        "Error converting value \"0c2d3928-aff2-44da-blaaah-blaaah\" to type 'System.Guid'. Path '[1].SectionId', line 9, position 51."
    ]
}
```

And when the Section Id guids are valid:

```
[
    {
        SectionId : "0c2d3928-aff2-44da-5d98-08d727c1a8b0",
        Name : "",
        Info : "Test Info",
        Tags : ["tag 1", "tag 2"]
    },
    {
        SectionId : "0c2d3928-aff2-44da-5d98-08d727c1a8b0",
        Name : "",
        Info : "Test Info",
        Tags : ["tag 3", "tag 2"]
    }
]
```

The result is:

```
{
    "[0].Name": [
        "Field Name is not provided but it is required",
        "Field Name is under minimum length. Lenght must be not less than 1 character(s)"
    ],
    "[1].Name": [
        "Field Name is not provided but it is required",
        "Field Name is under minimum length. Lenght must be not less than 1 character(s)"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *when there is a bind error - for example not valid string to be bind to guid - Model State contains only the errors from binding but non of other errors - attribute required or MaxLength and so on. Is this something expected?*

That's not the truth. The real reason is you're processing a **JSON payload**. The json payload must be **deserialized** into  `ICollection<SkillBindDto>` firstly and then the **validator** could validate it.

When processing your payload with **an invalid `GUID`** property, the **deserialization fails too early** so there'll be **no further binding/validation** for other properties.

> *Is there a way to get all model state errors on one trip?*

As I said above, the issue happens because the JSON Deserailziation fails.

If you would like using the JSON format, you tell MVC how to process the invalid property. For example, create a custom `JsonConverter` :

```
public class MyCustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dt= reader.Value;
        ... // because the processing rules depends on your business, 
        ... //     I can't write all the codes here.
        ... // e.g.
        ... //     create a null(object) or default(value) if invalid
    }
}
```

### An Easy Walkaround

As a much easier **walkaround**, you can send a **form payload instead of `application/json`**.

A [form payload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) is encoded as key-value pairs separated by '&', with a '=' between the key and the value, which looks like query string. When you submit a HTML `<form />` in old days, you're actually send a form payload.

Frist, remove the `[FromBody]` attribute in your action:

```
[HttpPost()]
public async Task<ActionResult<IReadOnlyCollection<SkillDto>>> Create([FromBody]ICollection<SkillBindDto> skills, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    ...
}
```

And then send the payload in format of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You might use [`new FormData(formElementId)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#Creating_a_FormData_object_from_scratch) to construct such a form payload. I create a helper function that maps a JSON to form-data :

```
function createFormPayload(name,o){
    var payload = {};
    function _objectNotNull(value){
        return value !== null && typeof value === "object";
    }
    function _create(prefix,obj) {
        for(var prop in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                var key = "";
                if(prefix){
                    key = isNaN(prop)? key = prefix + "." + prop : key = prefix + ".[" + prop + "]";
                }else{
                    key = isNaN(prop)? key = prop : key = "[" + prop + "]";
                }
                var value = obj[prop];
                if(_objectNotNull(value)) 
                    _create(key, value); 
                else 
                    payload[key]=value;
            }
        }
    };
    _create(name,o);
    return payload;
}
```

And now we can send the `skills` to form-data object:

```
var skills= [
    {
        "SectionId" : "0c2d3928-aff2-44da-blaaah-blaaah",
        "Name" : "",
        "Info" : "Test Info",
        "Tags" : ["tag 1", "tag 2"]
    }, {
        "SectionId" : "0c2d3928-aff2-44da-blaaah-blaaah",
        "Name" : "",
        "Info" : "Test Info 2",
        "Tags" : ["tag 3", "tag 2"]
    }
];

var data = createFormPayload("",skills) ;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/xxx/create",
    data: data,
    success: function(r){
        console.log(r);
    },
});
```

### Demo

When sending the above skills the actual payload will be :

```
POST https://localhost:5001/Home/Create
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

[0].SectionId=0c2d3928-aff2-44da-blaaah-blaaah&[0].Name=&[0].Info=Test Info&[0].Tags[1]=tag1&[0].Tags[2]=tag2&[1].SectionId=0c2d3928-aff2-44da-blaaah-blaaah&[1].Name=&[1].Info=TestInfo2&[1].Tags[1]=tag3&[1].Tags[2]=tag 2
```

And then you'll get a response that describes all the errors :

[image]

Comment: My API is consumed by other application that I have no control. So changing the payload is not a option. But the custom JsonConverter is a good suggestion that works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I will post the code that solves my problem. It is based on itminus answer. 
So finally I used a custom JsonConverter for Guids that works fine.

The custom JsonConverter - if can not convert the string from payload to Guid sets the corespondent field to empty Guid value, so the payload is serialized and can continue with other validations:

```
public sealed class JsonConverterDefaultGuid : JsonConverter<Guid>
{
    public override Guid ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Guid existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string value = (string)reader.Value;
        return Guid.TryParse(value, out var result) ? result : Guid.Empty; 
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Guid value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Next - create custom validation attribute witch check if the decorated property has a default value and add a model state error:

```
public class NotDefaultAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public const string DefaultErrorMessage = "The {0} field must not have default value";

    public NotDefaultAttribute() : base(DefaultErrorMessage)
    {

    }

    public NotDefaultAttribute(string errorMessage) : base(errorMessage)
    {

    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return !value.Equals(value.GetDefaultValue());
    }
}
```

The attribute use a extension method for default value generation to any object:

```
public static object GetDefaultValue(this object obj)
{
      var objType = obj.GetType();

      if (objType.IsValueType)
          return Activator.CreateInstance(objType);

     return null;
}
```

And all this is used like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonConverterDefaultGuid))]
[NotDefault(ValidationMessages.FieldInvalid)]
public Guid SectionId { get; set; }
```